# Unsure of Probability Terminology

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, terminology

I am not sure how to call the following property (I have forgotten my probability theory!). I'd be grateful if someone can tell me the keywords:

Suppose I have the following cartoon: I have a sequence of probability measures $ \mu_n $ each on the space of functions $ C_n = \{ f: [0,n] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \} $. Now it has the property that for $ f \in C_n $ and $ m > n $: $$ \mu_n (f) = \sum_{\substack{f' \in C_m \\ f'|_{[0,n]} = f}} \mu_m(f) $$
What is the correct terminology for this sort of filtration? Thank you.